# Вывод данных из БД на страницу

Tags: mysql

Пытаюсь вывести данные из таблицы в две колонки.
Первая колонка заполняется а вот вторая остаётся пустой, то есть просто ниже текст вставляется, не могу понять в чём проблема.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "mysql";
$password = "mysql";
$dbname = "wp";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT username, name FROM mailbox";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

 echo "<table border=3> 
 <tr><th>e-mail</th><th>name</th></tr>";

 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr><td>" . " " . $row["username"]. "<br>";
    echo "</tr></td>" . " " . $row["name"]. "<br>";
  }
}

?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: **name** есть в таблице **mailbox** ?

Comment: да, есть конечно.

Comment: Вот как у меня всё получается, то есть именно нейм не залазиет в колонку таблицы

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

он вывелся но не в таблице. замените

```
echo "<tr><td>" . " " . $row["username"]. "<br>";
echo "</tr></td>" . " " . $row["name"]. "<br>";
```

на

```
echo "<tr><td>" . " " . $row["username"]. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . " " . $row["name"]. "</td></tr>";
```